# How can I pass a value from an ASPX page to another in a different domain

Tags: asp.net, parameter-passing

I have an ASPX page in my Application. ASPX pages from other applications in different domain
can call this page. But how do I return a value to the calling ASPX page in a different application?

How an ASPX page can return a value to calling page in a different app?

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution is to use a web service [(here's an older introductory article)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972326.aspx). Failing that, the calling pages will likely have to be able to parse or scrape the content of your page in order to retrieve a return value.

Comment: We already have a WCF service for this purpose, but we need this page also should be able to call from a different application and return a value.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Your second application should be able to call the web service exposed by the first application, as long as it can provide whatever authentication you may have setup for the web service. This is what web services are inherently for -- passing data between different applications.